# Import statement desynchronises code execution

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

currently learning Javascript and building a simple web application. Here, I am trying to display a chart using apex charts. When I do not include the import statement highlighted, then the chart displays fine on the webpage, when an import (or any other code within that file) is included, the chart no longer appears on the webpage. I am only starting to understand the asynchronous nature of JS so I have assumed it has got to do something with that. Any help is appreciated!

```
import { datapoints } from "./main.js"; // When this line is commented out or removed, the chart renders fine

var options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'candlestick'
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [1147651200000,67.37,68.38,67.12,67.79],
        [1147737600000,68.10,68.25,64.75,64.98],
        [1147824000000,64.70,65.70,64.07,65.26],
        [1147910400000,65.68,66.26,63.12,63.18],
        [1147996800000,63.26,64.88,62.82,64.51],
        [1148256000000,63.87,63.99,62.77,63.38],
        [1148342400000,64.86,65.19,63.00,63.15],
        [1148428800000,62.99,63.65,61.56,63.34],
        [1148515200000,64.26,64.45,63.29,64.33],
        [1148601600000,64.31,64.56,63.14,63.55],
        [1148947200000,63.29,63.30,61.22,61.22],
        [1149033600000,61.76,61.79,58.69,59.77]

      ]
    }]
  }
  
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
  
chart.render();
```

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. I'm betting you'll see an error message there. (I'm not sure which one as there are at least two different common mistakes you could have made here).

Comment: I'm getting the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error but I've already defined "type": "module" in a package.json file

Comment: What does `package.json` have to do with this? That code is executing in a browser, not under Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Browsers support the `import` statement, but only when enabled in a module script. You can enable a module script by adding `type="module"` to your HTML script tag. Here's a simple example of setting up `import` statements for the browser:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="module" src="./script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```javascript
// script.js
import { datapoints } from "./main.js"; // this should work without errors

// ...
```

Note that if you do plan to scale an application, you may want to consider using a framework or a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), or [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/).